# Easiest way to build a horizontal hotend mount at home, without printing

Tags: diy-3d-printer, hotend, hardware, stability

For my Frankenstein's printer I am at a loss with the hotend mount. I cannot drill holes of 16 (upper diameter) and 12 mm (clamping diameter, 6mm high) which i would need to mount the E3D V6 clone I have.

What I am looking for: a hotend mount plate that tightly fixes the hotend while having some holes for screws to mount it to the horizontally moving x-y drives. As I cannot print yet, it needs to be manufacturable at home. I thought of something like this:
http://www.thingiverse.com/thing:285405
I could get a piece of wood thin enough to fit the 6mm gap for the hotend, would not really be able to put any screws through it along the flat axis. also I would have to glue the layer with a 16mm hole on top. Not to say that I don't own a drillbit of 16mm diameter...

Are there some completely different ideas around which I didn't think of yet?

Additional info: the x-y axes are made from a scanner bed and an underneath mounted dvd drive laser positioner. Ideally, I'd want to mount the hotend directly to the DVD drive but a) there is almost no space for that, and b) I'm pretty sure I will burn the DVD drive's motor somewhere along the way, so I don't want to put too much work in the individual DVD drive.

Answer (score 4):

You could cut a v-notch groove in a piece of plywood to hold one side of the groovemount neck, and then use a bolt through another piece of wood to push the neck into the V-notch.

There are lots of options when building RepStraps and JunkStraps. Really depends on what sort of hardware and fabrication capabilities you have on hand.

Answer (score 2):

If you do not have the tools to fabricate this component yourself, but have a 3D model available, I would suggest getting someone else to 3D print it for you.

There are multiple options for getting your model printed, such as:

- Friends
- Your local makerspace, library or similar
- [3D Hubs](https://www.3dhubs.com/)
- [MakeXYZ](https://www.makexyz.com/)
- [Shapeways](http://www.shapeways.com/)
- [Sculpteo](http://www.sculpteo.com/en/)
- and so on..

Good luck!

Comment: This is not an option for me since I want to reduce the bought parts as much as possible. Especially if I can't reuse them afterwards. Your repository of printing services and the idea might be very useful for others, though.